# a4j:commandButton doesn't render the element

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf, commandbutton

I've got a JSF page with `<rich:tabPanel>` which contains 4 tabs.

On the 4th tab I'm trying to use `<a4j:commandButton>` to execute the action and render `resulTable`.

Here is the shorten example

```
<rich:tab header="Journal">

    <h:form id="filterForm">
        <a4j:jsFunction name="submitByEnter"
                        action="#{smsLogList.refresh}" render="smsTable" />
        <s:div id="divSearch">
            <rich:collapsiblePanel header="#{messages['search']}"
                                   switchType="client">
                <h:panelGrid column="1">
                    <s:decorate template="/layout/edit.xhtml">
                        <ui:define name="label">Package number</ui:define>
                        <h:inputText id="packNum" style="width:200px"
                                     value="#{smsLogList.packNum}">
                            <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{smsLogList.refresh}"
                                      ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="1500"
                                      render="smsTable" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </s:decorate>

                    <!---some other search elements-->

                    <s:div styleClass="actionButtons">
                        <a4j:commandButton id="search" value="#{messages['search']}"
                                           render="smsTable" action="#{smsLogList.go}" />
                        <a4j:commandButton id="reset" value="#{messages['clear']}"
                                           onclick="document.getElementById('filterForm').reset();"
                                           action="#{smsLogList.clear}" render="divSearch,smsTable" />
                    </s:div>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </rich:collapsiblePanel>
        </s:div>

        <!--- results table-->

        <h:panelGrid id="smsTable">
            <s:div>
                <rich:dataTable value="#{smsLogList.resultList}" var="sms"
                                id="table" rendered="#{not empty smsLogList.resultList}">
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Type</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{sms.smsType}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <!---- some other columns-->

                </rich:dataTable>
                <rich:dataScroller for="table" />
            </s:div>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</rich:tab>
```

So, when I'm clicking on the `<a4j:commandButton>` - nothing happens, but if I'm switching to the other tab and back - the result is as necessary.
I tried to change a4j to `<h:commandButton>`, but after it's pressed the page switches to the first tab.

Is any solution how to work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.
I used `<h:form>` inside other `<h:form>`. It will not work anyway. When I remove internal  - the jsf works smooth and as it should.